# AuthenticationFailureHandler HttpServletResponse.sendError url

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have developed single page web application using Spring Boot and Spring MVC. I am using Spring Security and JWT to authenticate users. I have written a custom AuthenticationFailureHandler which works but I want to know how I can control the url that a user gets redirect to when an exception is thrown. My AuthenticationFailureHandler looks like this:

```
public class JwtAuthenticationFailureHandler implements AuthenticationFailureHandler {

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {     
        response.sendError(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value(), exception.getMessage());
    }
}
```

When the JWT expires the application throws an AccountExpiredException, the AuthenticationFailureHandler.onAuthenticationFailure method gets executed and the user gets redirected to the login page:

```
http://localhost:8080/login?sessionExpired=true
```

This is all good, but I have no idea how the sessionExpired=true query string is generated and I want to have some control over it. In the past I have used ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandlers like this:

```
Map<String, String> mappings = new HashMap<>();
mappings.put(BadCredentialsException.class.getCanonicalName(), BAD_CREDENTIALS_EXCEPTION_URL);
mappings.put(AccountExpiredException.class.getCanonicalName(), ACCOUNT_EXPIRED_EXCEPTION_URL);
mappings.put(CredentialsExpiredException.class.getCanonicalName(), CREDENTIALS_EXPIRED_EXCEPTION_URL);
mappings.put(DisabledException.class.getCanonicalName(), ACCOUNT_INACTIVE_EXCEPTION_URL);
mappings.put(LockedException.class.getCanonicalName(), ACCOUNT_LOCKED_EXCEPTION_URL);
mappings.put(ValidationException.class.getCanonicalName(), VALIDATION_EXCEPTION_URL);

ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler exceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler = new ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler();
exceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler.setExceptionMappings(mappings);
```

So based on the various exceptions above I would like to be able to redirect to the following URLs:

```
http://localhost:8080/login?error    
http://localhost:8080/login?accountexpired
http://localhost:8080/login?credentialsexpired
http://localhost:8080/login?accountlocked
http://localhost:8080/login?accountinactive
http://localhost:8080/login?validationerror
```

I'm not sure who to do this with response.sendError and I don't know how the sessionExpired=true query string is being generated. I have tried throwing different exceptions but the url never changes.

I have a couple of questions. Is it possible to control the URL when using HttpServletResponse.sendError and if not is it possible ot set the HttpStatus code when using ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler.sendRedirect?

Comment: `jwt` tokens are typically used in stateless, and browserless, interactions because browsers don't know what a JWT is. I'm not sure you should be returning 30x redirect codes for that type of interactions, the system should simply return a 401 Unauthorized if a JWT is invalid.

`sessions` on the other hand, are tracked by an `id` on the server and a `cookie` on the user agent.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to use the response.sendRedirect:

```
        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
            final HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
            if (session != null) {
                request.getSession().setAttribute(WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION, exception);
            }
          //here the logic to get the error type of the exception
          String errorMessage = ????

            redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response,
                    "http://localhost:8080/login?" + errorMessage);
        }
```